# How to Upgrade Mongo DB engine mmapv1 to Wired trigger?

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

I am having mongodb 3.0.7 with mmapv1 engine. Now I want to upgrade to Wired trigger. My operating system (OS) is Windows server R2 2012. can any one provide me the detailed steps for upgrading Mongo DB Engine?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using replication.

1 - You need to backup your database:

```
mongodump -d db_name YOUR_BACKUP_LOCATION
```

[mongodump documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/)

2 - Stop MongoDB service

3 - Change configuration

```
storage:
    dbPath: "YOUR_LOCATION"
    engine: wiredTiger
```

Use new location. It will be easier to go back if something goes wrong.

4 - Start MongoDB service

5 - Restore database from backup

```
mongorestore YOUR_BACKUP_LOCATION
```

[mongorestore documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/)

Done.

Comment: If my dbpath is "c:\data\db" and how I can tell that

Comment: First you simply connect with mongodump to your mongod instance (like with mongo) to backup database. your connection string will look more like this mongodump -d db_name -h localhost:27017 -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD -o c:\backup

Comment: storage:
    dbPath: "c:\data\db"
    engine: wiredTiger  can I give like this?

Comment: It will be fine. Remember to create backup first!